# spanning tree, how can I change the path?

Tags: switching, spanning-tree

I have 2 Switches I made either channel between them , but every switch is connected with other links through other switches that can reach the destination and the spanning tree makes the channel not designated and all messages does not send through it .

is there any way to select the path I want? ?

Is there any way to change the cost ?

Comment: Can you post your topology?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the root bridge and priority to modify the blocking/forwarding ports of STP.

It is dependant on your setup so without seeing the topology it is a little hard to assist with how you want the setup.

You can find some information on configuring STP on cisco devices here:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/spanning-tree-protocol/5234-5.html